# IOServiceMatching on AppleUSBCDCACMData IOClass: Anomaly?

Tags: macos, usb, iokit

I am trying to extract a list of all AppleUSBCDCACMData IOClass devices in my mac using the following code snippet (just some small scale modifications in apple sample code). The device is a usb modem which creates some 7 /dev/cu.usbmodemx device nodes.

```
    error = IOMasterPort(MACH_PORT_NULL, &masterPort);  

if(error){
    return ;
}
else{
    matchingDict = IOServiceMatching("AppleUSBCDCACMData");
    IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort,matchingDict,&modem_iterator);
    while(usbDevice = IOIteratorNext(modem_iterator))
    {

            }
```

My observation is, the iterator returned by IOServiceGetMatchingServices is empty (ie nothing to iterate on). But if i pass "AppleUSBCDCACMControl" as the parameter to IOServiceMatching, i get a iterator of a list of 7 elements - which is in conformance with the IORegistryExplorer view. See a screenshot of IORegistryExplorer here, http://tumblr.deepak.dk/post/1666218968/ioregistryexplorer
It appears that it is not possible to query IORegistry with arbitrary IOClass name strings? Since i faced the same issues with some non-standard proprietary IOClasses as well.
This can be reproduced using any USB modem (3g/HSDPA) which loads AppleUSBCDC driver.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IOService` objects can only be matched once [`registerService()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/KernelIOKitFramework/IOService_h/Classes/IOService/index.html#//apple_ref/cpp/instm/IOService/registerService/void/%28IOOptionBits%29) has been called for them. `AppleUSBCDCACMControl` does this, but `AppleUSBCDCACMData` does not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a specific reason for the registerService() to be omitted in     AppleUSBCDCACMData driver? What i was trying to do is to get the /dev path of all the devices associated with a modem via IOKit lib. That information is not there in     AppleUSBCDCACMControl entries of the IORegistry. Anyway there are multiple ways of getting this data. I could fix this by matching for     IOSerialBSDClient and then filtering out the relevant entries.

Comment: @Deepak: If you're looking for modems, you are probably better off matching `IOSerialStreamSync` and/or it's subclasses (`IORS232SerialStreamSync` and `IOModemSerialStreamSync`)

Comment: btw, IOSerialStreamSync is pretty much guaranteed to be matchable, otherwise IOSerialBSDClient would never work